# nginx with ssl taking long time to load

Tags: nginx

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this config file. if i'm executing this without certificate, everything works properly. but with ssl it's taking too much time to load the website. maybe it's because i'm force redirecting to https or something. I'm not much familiar with nginx. tried to google for similar issue but did not get the solution from anywhere.

```
server {

client_max_body_size 100M;
server_name myserver.xyz; # managed by Certbot


listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate PEM_FILE_PATH; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key PEM_FILE_PATH; # managed by Certbot
include CERTBOT_CONFIG_FILE; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam PEM_FILE; # managed by Certbot
root PROJECT_ROOT;
location / {

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location /api/ {

    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /40x.html {

}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {

}


}

server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name myserver.xyz;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWkma.png)

Comment: Can you post your nginx logs? Are there any messages in the web browser console when loading the page?

Comment: Are you loading something from `/` or from `/api/` location?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen yes. this is my API endpoint. used reverse proxy to achieve that.

Comment: @Bert no logs in console. this is working. everything is going good. force https and all working. the only issue i get is too much time to get data from /api and page load. if i remove https part, it is working properly.

Comment: Are you sure your `/api` endpoint works properly without `https`?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Yes it is.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen is it possible that it's doing multiple redirects?

Comment: Please show a screen capture from browser web developer tools Network tab, that one will show if there are any redirects happening.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen i have updated my post.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen https://i.stack.imgur.com/thFjt.png

Comment: Sorry, my instructions were not completely clear. Please Disable cache in developer tools, and then select the first request to your server in the output, and show "Timing" tab. Please make sure all entries in "Timing" tab are visible.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWkma.png

Comment: Sorry, still missing "clicking the first request and click on Timing tab".